# mpd to remote dlna

Tags: pulseaudio, mpd, upnp, dlna

I currently use an `mpd` with 4 configured outputs, wired to speakers in the ceilings as home-made "multiroom" audio system.

I would like to add wireless speakers, e.g. one like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00L26YDA4).

The question is:

How can I tell `mpd` that there is an output which is in fact remote a dlna/upnp (even aiyplay would be fine) ip-device ?

Is it possible at all ?

**Edit 1:**

[I found a way](https://swordfischer.me/2013/11/09/Raspberry-Pi-and-MPD-Sound-System/), though through `pulseaudio` and not `dlna` (which could be a use for one of my `Raspberry Pi`s).

Comment: I'm not sure this has to do with mpd as such. You probably want to configure your sound server (alsa, pulseaudio, etc.) to be aware of your new output so that applications can use it.

Comment: I though (but did not find anything related), since `mpd` has many output plugins, it could feature e.g. a `dlna` output.

Comment: The link in your edit is dead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that. However, you'll need a pulseaudio instance, and [pulseuadio-dlna](https://github.com/masmu/pulseaudio-dlna). This last part is a simple python software exposing all DLNA/UPnP renderers on your network as pulseaudio sinks. If you don't have any graphical session on your box, running pulseaudio in system-wide mode is still a possibility.

In my situation, I have an headless Linux box running mpd, streaming audio via snapcast to a Raspberry Pi and a Shield TV (running the Android version of snapcast), and I just added pulseaudio and pulseaudio-dlna to stream to a Chromecast Audio. mpd of course has built-in support for pulseaudio.